# Does a real representation induce a real representation

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be its subgroup. Suppose, $\rho$ be an irreducible representation of $H$ which can be realized over $\mathbb{R}$ and it remains irreducible after induction to $G$. Is it true that $Ind_{H}^{G} \rho$ can also be realized over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If you look at the definition of induction, you will see that if the original representation is realisable over a field $K$, then so is its induction.